# vector push_back in STL?

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I found a sample program which i tried for STL Vectors

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

/* This one may well work with some compilers/OS, and crash with
   others. Who said the STL was safe ?? */

int main() {
  vector<int> v;
  v.push_back(1);
  v.push_back(2);
  v.push_back(3);
  v.push_back(4);
  for (vector<int>::iterator i = v.begin();
       i != v.end(); i++) {
    cout << *i << endl;
    if (*i == 1) {
      v.push_back(5);
    }
  }
}
```

I was expecting result: 1 2 3 4 5

but, result is very weird - 1 0 3 4 0 0 33 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 49 0 1 2 3 4 5 5

I am guessing, this has some logic which i am missing because these don't seem like garbage values, because result is same always. 
After doing push_back, is iterator getting reset or something?
I have read it somewhere that appending to a vector while iterating over it isn't a good idea. My question is why?

After some search over internet,

```
     if (*i == 1) {
       size_t diff = i-v.begin();
       v.push_back(5);
       i = v.begin()+diff;
     }
```

this will solve the issue.

Comment: Keyword: iterator invalidation.

Comment: Regarding your workaround, have a look at [`std::distance()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) and [`std::advance()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance) instead of using the `-` and `+` operators.

Comment: Okay. which will be the pure STL solution. by single problem, i had figured out lot of things. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are modifying the `std::vector` while looping through it. When calling `std::vector::push_back()`, if its current `size()` is equal to its current `capacity()`, the `std::vector` will have to reallocate its internal data storage to increase its capacity before it can store the new value.  That reallocation will invalidate the loop `iterator` (the `end()` iterator is always invalidated, but you are re-evaluating it on each iteration, so it is OK in this case).

To do what you are attempting, either:

1. `reserve()` the `vector`'s capacity before entering the loop to avoid reallocation and thus avoid invalidating the loop `iterator`.
2. reset the iterators after each reallocation.
3. use a `std::list` instead, as the loop `iterator` will not get invalidated by `std::list::push_back()`.

Comment: got it. STL is a very deep sea.

Comment: reserve seems a good approach and will save some temp variable handing.

Comment: @Vishwadeep: don't confuse `reserve()` with `resize()`.  `reserve()` merely allocates the vector's internal memory and sets its `capacity()`, but does not affect its `size()`, so you would still need temp variables and `push_back()` and such. If you use `resize()` instead, which does affect `size()`, then you could avoid `push_back()` and use pointers/references to the `vector` elements directly.

Comment: yes you are correct. anyways i will go with the thumb rule that appending to a vector while iterating over it isn't a good idea. Else handle the situation.

Answer (score 3):

Because [`std::vector::push_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) might invalidate all iterators.

> If the new size() is greater than capacity() then all iterators and references (including the past-the-end iterator) are invalidated.

For your code, you can use [`std::vector::reserve`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) to avoid reallocation.

> Increase the capacity of the container to a value that's greater or equal to new_cap.

```
int main() {
  vector<int> v;
  v.reserve(5);  // ensure no reallocation until size() == 5
  v.push_back(1);
  v.push_back(2);
  v.push_back(3);
  v.push_back(4);
  for (vector<int>::iterator i = v.begin();
       i != v.end(); i++) {
    cout << *i << endl;
    if (*i == 1) {
      v.push_back(5);
    }
  }
}
```

And as you said, appending to a vector while iterating over it isn't a good idea.

Comment: oh ok. means it will invalidate when capacity is increased, this i would have done after 6-7 items, then i wouldn't have faced the issue. This gave me a better picture. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Some good options in existing answers, but worth mentioning another oft forgotten option when you know you're facing potential iterator invalidation due to push_back resizing beyond capacity:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
    cout << v[i] << endl;
    if (v[i] == 1)
        v.push_back(5);
}
```

It's "C style", but simple and intuitive.